# Angular Different package.json Per Environment?

Tags: angular

I have no clue if this is possible and hoping someone can shed some light if it is. Right now I have a production environment, testing environment, and QA environment. Each environment has different code snapshots and one of them being the package.json holding different version numbers of packages. We build our environments using Jenkins builds where we simply do `npm install` and then `ng build --prod` <- example environment

Is there any way to have a specific package.json per environment, so that when the environment is defined in `ng build`, it will pick up that package.json and install those dependencies?

I appreciate any type of feedback as to whether this is possible or not, and hopefully example of what can be done.

Comment: Sounds like the job for package.lock. It locks deps at certain versions. What's the issue here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to fix this from npm side, A good git strategy will help you better.

Perhaps, create two git branches with two package.json and from Jenkins side pull the branch according to environment.

So for example if you have two branch called `prod` (having prod package.json) and `dev` (having dev package.json)

You can clone the repo and switch to `prod` branch for prod env.

Same for dev.

Comment: That is the route I was thinking about taking and I think that this made it more clear as to how best achieve this. For some that read this, it might not be the "ideal" situation for everyone, but it is what I am looking for. Thank you